# Magento2.4.4 override class not working on windows

Tags: magento2

1. This is my di.xml:

   ```
   <preferencefor="Magento\CustomerSegment\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save" type="MyModule\CustomerSegment\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save"/>
   <preferencefor="Magento\CustomerSegment\Model\Segment\Condition\Combine" type="MyModule\CustomerSegment\Model\Segment\Condition\Combine" />
   ```
2. When I execute bin/magento setup:di:compile,I didn't find code in generated files.
   But first preference is executed.This is generated fidle in customerSegment:

[image]

Comment: Do you face any issue into compile command related to this?

Comment: No errors appear in the command

Comment: Then what you need?